# Membership.GetUser() always returns NULL on Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, macos, mono, asp.net-membership

I'm working on **ASP.NET MVC** project using **(VS 2019 Preview for Mac)** and got stuck on login and registration. When I call `Membership.GetUser(login)` I always got `NULL` as return. On **Windows 7's** VM I can get user info (password for example) but `Membership.ValidateUser()` still returns `false` even on a VM.

Well. I've checked `applicationName` property in `Web.config` and in a database. They are equal. 
My `Web.config`:

```xml
...
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="EntitiesModel" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10" minRequiredPasswordLength="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordFormat="Encrypted" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</membership>
...
```

In VS2019 for Mac output I've got this error when:

```
var pass = user.GetPassword();
```

The error is

> System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
>   Parameter name: s
>     at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes (System.String s) [0x00003] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs:1091 
>     at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.EncodePassword (System.String password, System.Web.Security.MembershipPasswordFormat passwordFormat, System.String salt) [0x000ee] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Security/SqlMembershipProvider.cs:1066 
>     at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPassword (System.String username, System.String passwordAnswer) [0x00053] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Security/SqlMembershipProvider.cs:545 
>     at System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.GetPassword (System.String passwordAnswer) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web.ApplicationServices/System.Web.Security/MembershipUser.cs:124 
>     at System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.GetPassword () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web.ApplicationServices/System.Web.Security/MembershipUser.cs:119 
>     at BLL.Core.UserManager.LoginAndGetUser (System.String login, System.String password, System.String& msg, System.String checkedRole) [0x00031] in [path to my project]/BLL/Core/UserManager.cs:107 
>     at BLL.Core.UserManager.Login (System.String login, System.String password, System.String& msg, System.String checkedRole) [0x0001c] in [path to my project]/BLL/Core/UserManager.cs:150

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net Core Apis ?

Comment: @MrinalKamboj ASP.Net MVC 5.2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC is an infrastructure that runs on Mac thanks to Mono. This is likely deprecated, as Mono on the server never had good performance or compatibility (especially when it comes to user management), your best bet is use `ASP.NET Core`, which runs on top of .NET Core (for Mac/Linux/Win).